# Can a wireless mouse dongle be used to connect to a cell phone?

Tags: bluetooth, mobile-phone, wireless-mouse

My laptop (Compaq Presario V3000) does not have bluetooth. Few months back I bought a bluetooth dongle to connect to my cell phone. One fine day the bluetooth dongle got damaged.

Now I also have this wireless mouse (Logitech M215), which also has a teeny-weeny dongle. What I am trying to figure out is, whether I can use the wireless mouse dongle to somehow connect to my cell-phone.

Is it possible?

Comment: and do what ???

Comment: What's the exact model of the dongle?

Comment: From the looks of the Logitech mouse specs on Logitech's website it looks that M215 is not a Bluetooth mouse hence the dongle is not Bluetooth dongle. It would also be beneficial if you did say what phone you're pairing with your laptop

Comment: I doubt your phone has any way to handle a mouse. The attachment for the wireless mouse would allow the phone to talk to the mouse, possibly... if your phone had any need for mice. I'm not sure what you desire to accomplish, even if it works.

Comment: I think DMX is trying to ask if he can use the mouse dongle to pair his cellphone with his laptop. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was trying to connect my phone to my laptop to transfer files between them...

Comment: @Darius yes you are right...

Comment: @DMX then MBreadley answer still holds unless you're willing to dish some money out for a Bluetooth mouse. I know that sending files to and from cellphone without cables is convenient but you can also do that with usb cable or more around way with your mSD card.

Answer (score 7):

The M215 isn't a Bluetooth device.  The M215 uses the Logitech® Advanced 2.4 GHz wireless technology, which is not the same as Bluetooth.  Unfortunately, you will not be able to connect your phone unless the dongle also supports Bluetooth.  From what I've read, that doesn't appear to be the case.  Sorry, you seem to be out of luck.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the answers... what i was trying to achieve is to connect my phone to my laptop using the wireless mice dongle... I was not clear on the bluetooth & wireless technology... I am using LG Optimus P500 running on Android 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

A bluetooth mouse can pair with a cell phone. I am actually using a Bluetooth mouse that is paired to my cell phone right now, but you may have to go to a electronic store and try out a Bluetooth cell phone and see which one that will pair to your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, if your phone has USB OTG Compatibility, and you have a suitable USB OTG adaptor. You connect the adaptor to your phone, and the mouse dongle to the adaptor. Its kind of clunky but it works on most android devices I have tested it on, from gingerbread to newer releases of android